# DLL profiling in Visual Studio 2013 professional cannot find VSPerfControl.Interop

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, profiling

I have tried debugging DLL in Visual Studio 2013 Pro and I keep getting these errors

Could not load file or assembly 'VSPerfControl.Interop, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

I have been stuck with this for a while and I would appreciate any comments. The MSDN website talks only about VS premium so I am not sure if profiling dll actually works on Professional

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385752.aspx

Comment: Problem was resolved by re-installing it in default folder.

Comment: So at first you've installed the Visuals studio in a directory rather than it's default option?

Comment: @SiavJosep It's been a while. Yes I think I was installing it on a different drive due to space limitations.

Comment: It seems that it has been the case for me as well. By re-installing the VS the issue got resolved. Also, please add your solution as an answer. It will make it easier for others to obtain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was resolved by re-installing it in default folder.

Comment: Hi Nenu. Your answer turned out in the "low quality posts" review queue. Could you accept your answer? This should prevent it to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you @J.Chomel. I am still new to Stack Overflow so did not know the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved without a re-install

You need to do:

1 - Open the Start menu, by pressing the Windows logo key Windows logo on your keyboard for example.

2 - On the Start menu, enter **dev**. This will bring a list of installed apps that match your search pattern. If you're looking for a different command prompt, try entering a different search term such as prompt.

3 - Choose the Developer Command Prompt (or the command prompt you want to use) - **RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR**

4 - Now you have to check if the VSPerfControl.Interop is in this path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools

5 - If isn't there, you have to re-install. If is there, you have to go to this path with your command prompt (*cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools*)

6 - After this, you have to execute this command line:

*gacutil /i VSPerfControl.Interop.dll*

Now re-open Visual Studio and be happy!!!